# Colorize lines in a grouped and facet_wrap ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(milieu = structure(c(3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("BUM", 
    "DDR", "ETB", "EXP", "HED", "KON", "MAT", "PER", "PMA", "TRA"
    ), class = "factor"), mycols = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 
    3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 
    3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 
    3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 
    3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Label = c("#00CCFF", 
    "#00FD03", "#3168FF", "#97CB00", "#98CBF8", "#CCFCCC", "#FB02FE", 
    "#FE9900", "#FF0200", "#FFFD00"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("Auslaender", "Umweltbelastung", 
    "OEPNV", "Kriminalitaet", "Einr. f. Kinder", "Mangel an Gruenflaechen", 
    "Gaststaette", "Geschaeft", "Bank", "Park", "Hausarzt", "Sportstaette", 
    "Einr. f. Jugendliche", "Einr. F. Aeltere"), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(0.0718023287061849, 
    0.0693420423225302, 0.0753384763664876, 0.0827043835101492, 0.109631516692048, 
    0.0765927537218141, 0.0870322381232645, 0.0515014684350035, 0.0683398169561522, 
    0.0554744519820495, 0.0363337127130046, 0.0463575341160886, 0.0671060291182815, 
    0.102443247236942), .Dim = 14L, .Dimnames = list(c("Geschaeft", 
    "Gaststaette", "Bank", "Hausarzt", "Einr. F. Aeltere", "Park", 
    "Sportstaette", "OEPNV", "Mangel an Gruenflaechen", "Kriminalitaet", 
    "Auslaender", "Umweltbelastung", "Einr. f. Kinder", "Einr. f. Jugendliche"
    )))), value = c(0.0468431771894094, 0.0916666666666667, 0.0654761904761905, 
    0.0905432595573441, 0.0761904761904762, 0.0672097759674134, 0.0869565217391304, 
    0.0650887573964497, 0.0762250453720508, 0.0518234165067179, 0.0855397148676171, 
    0.0604166666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0764587525150905, 0.0895238095238095, 
    0.0712830957230143, 0.075098814229249, 0.0631163708086785, 0.0780399274047187, 
    0.0383877159309021, 0.065173116089613, 0.0854166666666667, 0.0972222222222222, 
    0.0824949698189135, 0.060952380952381, 0.0529531568228106, 0.0731225296442688, 
    0.0828402366863905, 0.0725952813067151, 0.0806142034548944, 0.0712830957230143, 
    0.0833333333333333, 0.0912698412698413, 0.0704225352112676, 0.0628571428571429, 
    0.0672097759674134, 0.106719367588933, 0.0710059171597633, 0.108892921960073, 
    0.0940499040307102, 0.10183299389002, 0.104166666666667, 0.107142857142857, 
    0.100603621730382, 0.12, 0.116089613034623, 0.112648221343874, 
    0.112426035502959, 0.121597096188748, 0.0998080614203455, 0.0855397148676171, 
    0.0666666666666667, 0.0912698412698413, 0.0804828973843058, 0.0704761904761905, 
    0.0672097759674134, 0.0731225296442688, 0.0670611439842209, 0.0834845735027223, 
    0.0806142034548944, 0.0855397148676171, 0.0791666666666667, 0.0952380952380952, 
    0.0824949698189135, 0.0933333333333333, 0.114052953156823, 0.0810276679841897, 
    0.0788954635108481, 0.0780399274047187, 0.0825335892514395, 0.0529531568228106, 
    0.05625, 0.0456349206349206, 0.0583501006036217, 0.0666666666666667, 
    0.0366598778004073, 0.0434782608695652, 0.0571992110453649, 0.0344827586206897, 
    0.0633397312859885, 0.0692464358452139, 0.0645833333333333, 0.0694444444444444, 
    0.0422535211267606, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0692464358452139, 0.0711462450592885, 
    0.0749506903353057, 0.0598911070780399, 0.0959692898272553, 0.0672097759674134, 
    0.0541666666666667, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0422535211267606, 0.0628571428571429, 
    0.0509164969450102, 0.0454545454545455, 0.0532544378698225, 0.058076225045372, 
    0.072936660268714, 0.0244399185336049, 0.04375, 0.0416666666666667, 
    0.0663983903420523, 0.0228571428571429, 0.0509164969450102, 0.0237154150197628, 
    0.0236686390532544, 0.0217785843920145, 0.0441458733205374, 0.0468431771894094, 
    0.0479166666666667, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0402414486921529, 0.0438095238095238, 
    0.0468431771894094, 0.0454545454545455, 0.0512820512820513, 0.0417422867513612, 
    0.0518234165067179, 0.0753564154786151, 0.075, 0.0555555555555556, 
    0.0724346076458753, 0.0533333333333333, 0.0794297352342159, 0.075098814229249, 
    0.0788954635108481, 0.0598911070780399, 0.0460652591170825, 0.122199592668024, 
    0.0875, 0.0892857142857143, 0.0945674044265594, 0.11047619047619, 
    0.109979633401222, 0.0869565217391304, 0.120315581854043, 0.105263157894737, 
    0.0978886756238004), y = structure(c(3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("BUM", 
    "DDR", "ETB", "EXP", "HED", "KON", "MAT", "PER", "PMA", "TRA"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("milieu", "mycols", "variable", 
    "value", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -140L), class = "data.frame")
```

and want to plot it, according to [ggplot2 plot table as lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985181/ggplot2-plot-table-as-lines) (Thanks Ramnath) with:

```
ggplot(mdf, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_line(data = transform(mdf, milieu = NULL), aes(group = y), colour = 'grey80')+
  geom_line(aes(group = milieu)) +
  scale_colour_manual(value=mdf$mycols) +
  facet_wrap(~milieu) +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

The plot looks so far ok, but I can't set the colors of the lines (right now black) in each group to the according colors in mdf$mycols...

[image]

Has someone an idea how I can set the colors in the plot?
Thanks for your help!
Dominik

Comment: A humble suggestion: Making each black line a different color is redundant. The facet titles (BUM, DDR, ETB, etc.) already contain that information.

Comment: i agree joran. that was my suggestion too!

Comment: The reason is, that the color family indicates to which meta group a group belongs to. Blueish colors e.g. belong to the meta group of the leading milieus (ETB, PER and PMA).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you would do it in this case. You can control the thickness of the dark lines by changing "size" and the lightness of the other lines by changing "alpha". The only purpose of the colors I can see is that you don't need to use a legend and can easily look up the figure to compare different facets.

```
p1 = ggplot(mdf, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = mycols)) + 
  geom_line(data = transform(mdf, milieu = NULL), aes(group = y), alpha = 0.5) +   
  geom_line(aes(group = milieu, colour = mycols), size = 1.2) + 
  scale_colour_identity() + 
  facet_wrap(~ milieu) +
  theme_bw() +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  opts(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: That is nearly exactly what I was looking for. Except I do `geom_line(data = transform(mdf, milieu = NULL), aes(group = y), colour = 'grey80')+
  geom_line(aes(group = milieu, colour=mycols)) +
  scale_colour_identity() +`
Thanks Ramnath.